# strtotime error empty time parameter when stored into a variable

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to calculate the difference in minutes between two database fields using php.
the first field (attendance) is timestamp, and the second field (check_in) is time.

this is the PHP code I tried:

```
$sql = "
    select e.attendance, s.check_in, s.check_out
    from employee e
    inner join my_schedule s on s.id = e.sch_id
    where e.emp_id = '".$emp_id."'
";
$query = mysql_query($sql);
if ($query) {
    $row = mysql_fetch_array($query);
    echo 'employee checked in at '.strtotime($row['attendance']); // employee checked in at 2015-11-18 08:48:23  
    $late = round((strtotime($row['check_in']) - strtotime($row['attendance']))/60,0);
    if ($late < 0) {
        echo "you're late!!";
    }
```

the "you're late" message did appear but there's also an error message :

> strtotime() [function.strtotime]: Called with an empty time parameter.
>   in C:\Program Files\xampp\htdocs\myproject\page1.php

why do the error only appear when I store the value from strtotime() into a variable?

I'm using :

Current PHP version: 5.0.5

MySQL 4.1.14

UPDATE:

this is the result of `echo var_dump($row['attendance']);` (data type `timestamp`)

> string(19) "2015-11-18 08:48:23"

and this is `echo var_dump($row['check_in']);` (data type `time`)

> string(8) "08:00:00"

is it normal that PHP perceives those fields as string instead of time?

UPDATE 2 :
I found the source of the problem! the query used a parameter (emp_id) and one of the emp_id returns a zero result so the strtotime returned the error.

the solution is that I added an `IF` clause to make sure that the rows have a valid value before running strtotime.

```
if ($row['check_in'] != '' && $row['attendance'] != '') {
    $late = round((strtotime($row['check_in']) - strtotime($row['attendance']))/60,0);
}
```

Comment: What's within `$row['check_in']`

Comment: Can you dump the `$row` array so we're sure that the data is there? Also, what is that PHP version, can you recheck that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue here is that strtotime expects a date, not just a time. So you can extract the date from your attendance like this:

```
$attendance = "2015-11-18 08:48:23";
$check_in = "08:00:00";
if ( strlen($check_in) <= 8 ) { // Does not include date. Prepend it automatically:
    $parts = explode(" ",$attendance);
    $attendance_date = $parts[0];
    $check_in = "{$attendance_date} {$check_in}";
}
$late = round((strtotime($check_in) - strtotime($attendance))/60,0);
```

Just to be clear before we run our calculations we want to end up with:

```
$attendance = "2015-11-18 08:48:23";
$check_in = "2015-11-18 08:00:00";
```

Here are some more examples of `strtotime()`

```
echo strtotime("2015-11-18 08:48:23"),"\n";
echo strtotime("18 November 2015"),"\n";
echo strtotime("now"),"\n";
echo strtotime("+1 day"),"\n";
echo strtotime("+1 week"),"\n";
echo strtotime("+1 week 2 days 3 hours 4 seconds"),"\n";
echo strtotime("last Monday"),"\n";
echo strtotime("next Friday"),"\n";
```

Read more: [php.net/strtotime](http://php.net/strtotime)

Comment: thanks for the response. I found out that the problem was the query returned empty string which would be used by strtotime().

I used `date("H:i:s",$row['attendance']);` instead of `explode` to get the time part from a variable. which do you think is more appropriate?

Comment: @dapidmini using ````date()```` is good if you just want to get today's date. Without knowing your use case, as long as it's working for you, that seems like a great way to do it.

Comment: Passing ````$row['attendance']```` as the second parameter to ````date()```` doesn't seem like it will work though, as in your example it was a string. The second parameter should be a timestamp like ````strtotime()```` or ````time()```` - you should try printing out the input values before you run your ````$late```` calculation, you're going to want something in the format of ````Y-m-d H:i:s```` like ````2015-11-18 08:00:00```` so in other words you probably will need to use ````date('Y-m-d',strtotime($row['attendance']))```` then add the hours, minutes, and seconds. Good luck!

Answer (score -1):

if this is comes in form of warning then put @ before the strtotime().

```
$late = @strtotime($row['check_in']) - @strtotime($row['attendance']);
```

its just hide warnings.

Comment: Don't suggest to hide php errors with ``@``. That achieve nothing, suggest an answer where the code doesn't produce erros.